# Trying to split server response for blackberry app

Tags: blackberry

I am getting the response from the web service as follows:

```
response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
String result =  response.toString();
```

The "result" is a long string that consist "CredentialAccepted < / > FirstName < / > LastName < / > Picture". I need to split this result at the tags < / >. I tried the following but BlackBerry does not support. Any help?

```
List<String> list_result = Arrays.asList(result.split("</>"));
```

Comment: I changed it to 1.3. I get the error "The method split(String) is undefined for the type String". I am using it split my "result". How should I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that:

```
    public static String[] split(String original, String separator) {
        Vector nodes = new Vector();

        String trimmed = original.trim();

        int start = 0;
        int end;
        while ((end = trimmed.indexOf(separator, start)) != -1) {
            nodes.addElement(trimmed.substring(start, end));
            start = end + separator.length();
        }

        if (start < trimmed.length()) {
            nodes.addElement(trimmed.substring(start));
        }

        String[] result = new String[nodes.size()];
        nodes.copyInto(result);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Good answer ... just for reference, RIM has posted some utility code for [performing String splits, replace and replaceAll operations](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/String-Manipulation-split-replace-replaceAll/ta-p/620038)

Comment: Did you take a look on it? There is one comment to this code (mine :)). Do you agree with it?

Comment: Yes Eugen I used your code to do the "split" of the response received from the web service. Nate's link has helped clarrify it further. But I have used the code you posted.

Comment: Eugen, that's pretty funny!  I guess it's a small world.  Your comment is actually hidden on that page, unless you expand the comments section.  Yes, I do agree with you.  It looks like that code should only be used for applications where performance is not critical, and that null pointer bug (two conditions in the `if` statement reversed) obviously shows that they didn't run that code through unit tests.  By the way, I just stumbled randomly back on to this page ... because you didn't put `@Nate` into your comment, I wasn't automatically notified.  I'm glad I did, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nate, Thanks a lot for feedback. I'm relatively new on Stackoverflow and don't know yet details about effective communication here. But I'm learning and would like to continue friendship :)

Comment: You're welcome.  I've learned a lot from many of your great answers already!